# export symfony query via console

Tags: php, linux, symfony

I'm writing a deployment plan. And I need to export the query result as a SQL dump or CSV in Symfony.

I've found that following command returns an actual array output to the console:

```sql
bin/console doctrine:query:sql "select * from happy_ratings"
```

What I actually need is to have the results transformed to CSV, JSON or any plain file format.

I wonder if Symfony had any such feature out of the box or is there a Linux command to do this.

Comment: Could you describe what obstacles you've faced? `doctrine:query:sql` seems to be the right way to execute an SQL. Could you also add a more info what's wrong with it?

Comment: for more context, I'm writing a deployment plan.
bin/console doctrine:query:sql "select * from happy_ratings" returns an actual array output to the console. 
what I actually need is to have the results transformed to CSV, JSON or any plain file format. I wonder if Symfony had any such feature OOTB

Comment: If it prints out the result into console, can you pipe it to a file? E.g.: `bin/console doctrine:query:sql "select * from happy_ratings" > out.sql`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use `doctrine:query:sql` and have user with file privileges granted you can use [select into outfile](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html) and have csv file output

i'd suggest using tested [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html) to dump single table

`mysqldump -uUSER -p MY_DATABASE happy_ratings`